# Ubuntu 18.04LTS KVM VM Not Assigned IP by Router DHCP

Tags: ubuntu, routing, kvm-virtualization

I'm setting up KVM on Bionic Beaver, however my router isn't assigning the VM an IP address. I can however see it from the host.

Here are my netplan settings:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.26/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1]
      interfaces:
        - enp4s0
```

My host is set to be static on 192.168.0.26 and I can login just fine.

KVM setting:

```
virt-install ...
            --network bridge=br0,model=virtio
```

I've also added the iptable rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i br0 -j ACCEPT
```

However no joy at all, can't see another available device on the router screen.

UPDATE

I'm using a cloud image with the following cloud config:

```
#cloud-config
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens2:
      dhcp4: yes
users:
  - name: james
    groups: users, admin
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa
```

It's actually worked once, the VM was assigned an IP and access was straight-forward. But not on any subsequent attempts.

Thanks,

Comment: i aint see a nat rule?

Comment: Would that look like: iptables -A FORWARD -p all -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT?

Answer (score 0):

i use a routed config, that means my bridge isnt directly connected to the eth interface

```
iface ens3 inet static
address x. x. x. x
subnet x. x. x. x
 gateway x. x. x. x
post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens3/proxy_arp
    post-up /etc/iptab_up
    post_down /etc/iptab_down

auto vmbr0
#NAT sub network, not bridged
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  10.0.0.1
    netmask  255.0.0.0
    bridge_ports none
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_fd 0
    post-up   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-up         iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/8' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/8' -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
```

replace ens3/vmbr0 with your interfaces

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you post a netplan example?

Comment: sorry i alwqys uninstall betplan and replace it with ifupdown

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the answer wasn't that there was anything wrong with configuration. One of my previous cloud-init attempts had modified the network settings in a way I could not solve.

To fix this, I started with a fresh cloud image (originally Xenial as I was sceptical then back to Bionic) and it attached to the bridge just fine. My advice: use a fresh image with every attempt to make the installation immutable.